# Sending data from one tab to another which contains a spinner

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner

I want to send data from one tab to another. The one which will receive the data contains a spinner. When that data is passed on, I want to the spinner to change its selection to the one given within the data (it'll be the same as one of the spinner items).

Any ideas how I can use Bundle to do this?

Comment: Please post some code about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

is this in same activity or in a new activity ?

Same activity:

make an onClickListener and change the items in the spinner.

New Activity:

use

```
Inten intent = new Intent(yourclassname.this, targetClassname.class);
intent.putExtra("ID",DATA);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

it would help if you provide some code, but for now I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As option make array holding data for a spinner static and then create a static method in you destination activity something like this:

```
   public static void setSpinnerData (String[] data) {
     spinnerData = data; 
   }
```

Then call something like this YourActivity.setSpinnerData (myArray);

Alternativerly you can consider saving data to the application object which is the same for all activities.

Comment: To update the spinner you need the activity instance, which you cannot access from the static method.

Answer (score 0):

You may send the data (something small like a string or an ID) using a broadcast.
In the tab where the data is generated

```
final Intent i = new Intent(IConstants.UPDATE_SPINNER);
i.putExtra(IConstants.DATA_UPDATE, data);
this.sendBroadcast(i)
```

IConstants.UPDATE_SPINNER and DATA_UPDATE are just Strings used to identify your message by the receiver. You may also put them in your main activity instead of the interface I used.

In the tab with your spinner, declare an inner class for a broadcast receiver, it can access the spinner of the outer class.

```
private final class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if( IConstants.UPDATE_SPINNER.equals(intent.getAction()) ) {
        final String data = intent.getIntExtra(IConstants.DATA_UPDATE, "");
            // update your spinner
        return;
        }
        // process other messages ...
    }
}
```

Register the broadcast receiver like this, e.g. in onCreate() or onResume()

```
this.broadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
final IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter(IConstants.UPDATE_SPINNER);
// for more actions you can add them like this: 
// f.addAction(IConstants.UPDATE_ONOTHER_WIDGET);
this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, f);
```

Remember to unregister in onDestroy() or onPause().

Another option would be to use a handler and send messages to the handler. However, you would need the handler, which is located in the receiver, to be accessible in the sender. This way your fragments or activities (the tabs) would be stronger coupled.